# How can I print the list [[4],[42],[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2,2]] as [4,42,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2] in python?

Tags: python, sorting

I have to sort the list based on frequency of occurrence and I am trying this way but getting stuck.

[Code snippet of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdS7m.png)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import itertools

some_list = [[4], [42], [1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
flat = list(itertools.chain(*some_list))
print(flat)
```

Orrrr some black magic:

```py
some_list = [[4], [42], [1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
flat = sum(some_list, [])
print(flat)
```